# Android Things 0.5.1 boot failed on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things, android-things-console

I've tested Android Things 0.4.1 image which I've downloaded before builds moving into console on RPI3 successfully but every image I've build with Android Things Console with empty bundle failed to boot even image 0.4.1 I've build with Android Things console failed to boot, Here is serial console error:

```
U-Boot 2017.07-03124-gc35995ad17 (Aug 18 2017 - 02:52:42 +0000)

DRAM:  944 MiB
RPI 3 Model B (0xa22082)
MMC:   mmc@7e300000: 0
reading uboot.env
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   No ethernet found.
ANDROID: Attempting slot b, tries remaining 7
ANDROID: Booting slot: b
ANDROID: reboot reason: "(none)"
** Invalid Android Image header **
Android boot failed, error -1.
resetting ...
U-

U-Boot 2017.07-03124-gc35995ad17 (Aug 18 2017 - 02:52:42 +0000)

DRAM:  944 MiB
RPI 3 Model B (0xa22082)
MMC:   mmc@7e300000: 0
reading uboot.env
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   No ethernet found.
ANDROID: Attempting slot c, tries remaining 7
ANDROID: Booting slot: c
ANDROID: reboot reason: "(none)"
** Wrong ISO Ident: 


 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstےے‹ےےےےےےےےےےےےےے~ےےےےےےےےےے„ےےےےےےےےےےےےےے‍ےےژےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے—ےےےےےےےےœےےےے±ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےئےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےظےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےطےےîےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےéےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےَےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے)ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےDےےےےےےےےےے0123456ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےZےےےےHےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےYےےrےےےےےے_ےےےےےےےےdےےfےےےےےےjےےےےےےےےoےےےےےے‡ےےےےvےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےœےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے¯ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے©ےےےےےےےےےےےےبےے²³´µےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےأےےےےےےےےےےقےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےَےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے
                                                                                                                                             ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےAndroid boot failed, error -1.
resetting ...
U-

U-Boot 2017.07-03124-gc35995ad17 (Aug 18 2017 - 02:52:42 +0000)

DRAM:  944 MiB
RPI 3 Model B (0xa22082)
MMC:   mmc@7e300000: 0
reading uboot.env
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   No ethernet found.
ANDROID: Attempting slot d, tries remaining 7
ANDROID: Booting slot: d
ANDROID: reboot reason: "(none)"
** Wrong ISO Ident: 


 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstےے‹ےےےےےےےےےےےےےے~ےےےےےےےےےے„ےےےےےےےےےےےےےے‍ےےژےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے—ےےےےےےےےœےےےے±ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےئےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےظےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےطےےîےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےéےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےَےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے)ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےDےےےےےےےےےے0123456ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےZےےےےHےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےYےےrےےےےےے_ےےےےےےےےdےےfےےےےےےjےےےےےےےےoےےےےےے‡ےےےےvےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےœےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے¯ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے©ےےےےےےےےےےےےبےے²³´µےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےأےےےےےےےےےےقےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےَےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےے
                                                                                                                                             ےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےےAndroid boot failed, error -1.
resetting ...
U-

U-Boot 2017.07-03124-gc35995ad17 (Aug 18 2017 - 02:52:42 +0000)

DRAM:  944 MiB
RPI 3 Model B (0xa22082)
MMC:   mmc@7e300000: 0
reading uboot.env
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   No ethernet found.
ANDROID: Attempting slot a, tries remaining 6
ANDROID: Booting slot: a
ANDROID: reboot reason: "(none)"
Booting kernel at 0x1000000 with fdt at 2fffa100...
```

Comment: Which version are you trying to install? The title says 0.5.1, but the description says 0.4.1. If it is 0.4.1, please try using an image with the latest version.

Comment: @Devunwired I'm sorry for unclear question, What I'm trying to say is version 0.4.1 working on same device but version 0.5.1 not working even if I build version 0.4.1 myself with empty bundle again it's not working.

Comment: Does the board boot successfully despite these errors? The last line "Booting kernel at ..." indicates that it did eventually boot to the correct slot.

Comment: @Devunwired No it doesn't, Nothing working no HDMI output or LAN just serial communication working.